# Javascript - Functions won´t run the same way after the first time

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am new learning front-end and Javascript and I am designing a game ¨to learn the abecedary" on my own to achieve that.

My intention is to:

- 1st - Randomnly put the abecedary letters in the gameboard.
- 2nd - The user selects the first one (A, for instance). **The code assigns the firstSelectedLetter class**
- 3rd - The user selects the one that comes
  after the 1st selected (B, on this case) **The code assigns the
  secondSelectedLetter class**
- 4rd - The code compares both letters
  selected and and if the 2nd one comes after the 1st selected letter
  it **assigns the class corrected**.

Now, I have achieved all of these steps. But when I keep playing and select the letter C (or any other letter), the code won´t split between the 2nd and 3rd steps, and it assigns both classes (firstSelectedLetter and secondSelectedLetter) to the clicked letter. It compares the same letter and of course it´s wrong and the game ends.

[image: See the console logs here:]

The first time it has found out that the letter A has a 1, and the letter B has a 2. It compares both of them and says that I am right because the 2 = 1+1.

Buuut, when I keep playing and I choose letter C it just assigns both classes, compares the same latter and booom.

[image: See the log fromt the DevTools]

I have tried a lot of combinations, and tons of work arounds. But I am pretty sure I am missing something that I have not yet learned. I hope you guys can teach that to me and help others :)

Here´s the fiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/alejandroarag/qb91kean/

```
    // First I create the array with the abecedary letters
var abecedary = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];


// Second, I use this function to shuffle the letters randomly
function shuffleAbecedary() {
    var result;
    result = abecedary.sort(function () {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });
    return result;
}

//From this function i got on the internet i get the position on the letters on the alphabet (like 1st, 2nd...)
function alphabetPosition(text) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var code = text.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(i)
        if (code > 64 && code < 91) result += (code - 64) + " ";
    }

    return result.slice(0, result.length - 1);
}

// This function prints the letter in a DIV with a class and a dataset value that I will use later on
function lettersPrint() {
    var gameBoard = document.querySelector("#gameboard");
    var shuffledLetters = shuffleAbecedary();
    gameBoard.innerHTML = "";

    shuffledLetters.forEach(function (element) {
        var letter = document.createElement("div");
        letter.innerHTML = "<div class='letter' data-valor= " + element + ">" +
            "<div class='letter_content'>" +
            element +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";
        //I put all of them inside the gameBoard ID
        gameBoard.appendChild(letter);
    });

}

function firstToSelect() {
    var firstSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".firstLetterSelected:not(.correct)");

    if (firstSelected.length > 0) {
        return
    }

    this.classList.add("selected");
    this.classList.add("firstLetterSelected");

    document.querySelectorAll(".letter:not(.selected)").forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", secondToSelect);
    });
}


function secondToSelect() {
    var firstSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".firstLetterSelected:not(.correct)");
    var secondSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".secondLetterSelected:not(.correct)");

    if (secondSelected.length > 0) {
        return
    }

    this.classList.add("selected");
    this.classList.add("secondLetterSelected");

    var lettersToCompare = firstSelected + secondSelected;


    compare(lettersToCompare);
}

function compare(lettersToCompare) {
    var firstLetter = document.querySelectorAll(".firstLetterSelected:not(.correct)");
    var secondLetter = document.querySelectorAll(".secondLetterSelected:not(.correct)");
    var firstLetterToCompare = alphabetPosition(firstLetter[0].dataset.valor);
    var secondLetterToCompare = alphabetPosition(secondLetter[0].dataset.valor);

    var lettersToCompare = firstLetterToCompare + "," + secondLetterToCompare;

    var theLetters = document.querySelectorAll(".selected:not(.correct)")
    var letsCompare = lettersToCompare.split(",");

    console.log(letsCompare[0]);
    console.log(letsCompare[1]);

    if (letsCompare[0] == letsCompare[1] - 1) {
        console.log("You are right!");
        correct(theLetters);

    } else {
        console.log("Opps you are not right!");
        error(theLetters);
    }
}

function correct(theLetters) {
    theLetters.forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.add("correct");
    });
}

function error(theLetters) {


    //    theLetters.forEach(function (element) {
    //        element.classList.add("error");
    //
    //        setTimeout(
    //            function () {
    //                theLetters.forEach(function (element) {
    //                    element.classList.remove("selected");
    //                    element.classList.remove("error");
    //                });
    //            }, 1000);
    //    });
}

lettersPrint();
document.querySelectorAll(".letter").forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", firstToSelect);
});
```

Comment: Your comments (in code) tend to drop off from being verbose, after a certain point. As such following your logic might be a tad bit difficult. I'd suggest inserting more code comments, and also if possible, explain in code comments your mental logic, to get help on this one. It will help you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look and I think the big problem is here

```js
    document.querySelectorAll(".letter:not(.selected)").forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", secondToSelect);
    });
```

You register a second click listener but never get rid of it?

First of all I like the game, it's a nice exercise for you.

You definitely need to do move some of the *hidden state* of the game out
of the HTML and CSS and into the code, you will be able to achieve much more with
a little bit of *shuffling responsibility* around.

Right now the state is in the CSS classes and you fetch which one is the
first and which one is the second by looking at it but you are making it
complicated; here's what I would do.

```js
var choices = [] // a list of letters chosen by the player

function isCorrect() {
    return choices.length == 2 & choices[0] < choices[1] // this is just for two letters at a time but could be made longer
}

function clear() {
  choices = []
}

function select(a) {
  if (choices.length == 2) {
    return
  }
  choices.push(a)
}
```

Then instead of registering 2 click listener I would register 1 that would use `select` to add the value to the choices and then call `isCorrect` to know if
it should update the UI and state (calling `clear` and removing letters from the board) or not.

Bonus: you can compare a lot of values in javascript and in this case you should try `"a" < "b"` and see what happens!

Comment: Hello, you gave me the answer. I had to take out the event listener. Right now my code is super messy and with a lot of adding and removing event listener. But it works and I understand my code at my level right now. 

Nevertheless, I will make it better and easier. 

Also, I liked the idea of not making paring of choices, so I will be touching my code much more!! 

But that´s what I wanted, to make something from myself and for me to understand. I was looking exactly for that answer: I need to remove the event listener! Check the game here https://jsfiddle.net/alejandroarag/qb91kean/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be overly complex from what I am understanding you are wanting to
achieve. This makes me think I may have misunderstood the objective and game logic. If that is case, the following simplification may not be appropriate.

Basically, I think you can cut back on most of the code.

```js
// first letter should always be A? If so, we can set lastSelected = (charCode 64). 
var lastSelected = String.fromCharCode(64), abecedary = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

// shuffle the letters randomly
function shuffle(arr) {
    var result = arr.sort(function () {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });
    return result;
}

function checkOrder(e){
  var s = this.textContent;
  if ((s.charCodeAt(0) - 1) != lastSelected.charCodeAt(0)){
    this.classList.add("err");
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("err");
    this.classList.add("correct");
    lastSelected = s;
  }
}

shuffle(abecedary);

var l, board = document.getElementById("board");
for(i=0;i<abecedary.length;i++){
  l = document.createElement("div");
  l.setAttribute("class","letter");
  l.textContent = abecedary[i];
  l.addEventListener("click",checkOrder,false);
  board.appendChild(l);
}
```

```css
#board {
  max-width:216px;
}
.letter {
  display:inline-block;
  width:24px;
  line-height:24px;
  text-align:center;
}
.err {
  background:#f99;
}
.correct {
  background:#9f9;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```